# How can i do hide and show the header view with animation effect while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to achieve hide and show the header view with slow animation like facebook while scrolling the collection view.

Image :

[image]

My code :

```
if (currentContentOffset > self.previousContentOffset) {


    heightConstraintView.constant = 0;
    HeaderView.hidden = YES;

} else if (currentContentOffset < self.previousContentOffset) {

    heightConstraintView.constant = 57;
    HeaderView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: did you try using `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` add it in viewDidLoad and check if thats what you want

Comment: it is not a navigation controller. its just a uiview

Comment: please put this code to objective c.

Comment: Use navigation controller instead of uiview

Comment: @geeks-of-geeks : Sorry my mistake dont use the code above it will add two constraints rather than modifying the existing constraint lemme update

Comment: ok sandeep......

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIView` native animation method. Please note `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` is necessary. Do same to **Unhide** your view

```
heightConstraintView.constant = 57;
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                HeaderView.hidden = NO;
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a collectionView, then what I would suggest is to try using the navigationbar like View as a headerView of collectionView itself, here is how I do it, when I use need to accomplish something similar:

use the delegate methods as :

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section != 0 {
    return pageControl.numberOfPages
    }
    return 0 //so no cells are displayed for this header, remember to do the same for sizeForItemAtIndex and CellForItemAtIndex too
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        //add your custom navigation bar like View here
    }
      return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

In this approach, the animation of the header view when you scroll will be taken care of by the collection view itself, and it will only appear again if you rach to the top.

Answer (score -1):

It can easily be achieved if you use `navigationBar`. iOS gives `UINavigationController` a simple property that masks some complex behaviour. If you set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` to be `true` for any `UINavigationController`, then iOS automatically adds a tap gesture recogniser to your view to handle hiding (and showing) the navigation bar as needed. This means you can mimic Safari's navigation bar behaviour in just one line of code in `viewDidAppear`, like this:

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

Comment: But i achieve only on view that is the biggest problem.